# PayPal In-Context Checkout with REST SDK

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using the PHP REST SDK for Express Checkouts and my code is based on this example : http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html

This works great, except I'm not sure how to integrate it with the new In-Context checkout. From what I understand, I just need the EC token so I can use it with the in-context checkout and get a URL like this `https://sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=EC-TOKEN`, but I can't find how to get the EC token only.

When creating a payment with the REST SDK, all you get is the approval url `https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-TOKEN`. I *could* extract the token from the URL but that doesn't seem like a good idea. There has to be a way to get the EC token, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It's specific to `Express Checkout` (_Classic API_) only. So unless corrected by Paypal folk In-Context is (still) not supported in REST API (which btw uses `Paypal Payment` to somewhat refer to the _Classic API_ Express Checkout flow). Hth...

Comment: So In-Context doesn't support the REST API ? Isn't In-Context kind of a new thing? Weird that they would not support the REST API...especially since it works if you just take the token from the URL. Anyways, thanks for the help. I hope they add official support for the REST API soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, the REST API doesn't work (yet) with In-Context but if anyone wants to make it work, here's one simple line of PHP to change the approval_url to the In-Context url (**only for testing purposes, I don't recommend using it in prod until we get official support**) :

`$approvalUrl = str_replace('cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&', 'checkoutnow?', $payment->getApprovalLink());`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the trick if you'd like to call the in-context experience without tampering the redirect url

1. Put the script in your frontend page:

```html
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, ref = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.async = true;
      js.src = "//www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal.v1.js";
      ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }
  }(document, "script", "paypal-js"));
</script>
```

2. Place the button with data tags, into your form codes:

```html
<input type="image" data-paypal-button="true" data-paypal-sandbox="true" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/checkout-logo-large.png" alt="Check out with PayPal" />
```

This way you would make the form submitted to your REST api checkout page, and control the in-contect redirect only with frontend codes

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that helps me. Even if I redirect frontend side, I still don't have the EC token to pass to In-Context, unless there's another way to do it? I can't find the script you referenced in paypal's doc. The only doc I can find about In-Context is this : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/integration/

Comment: First thing first, this works when you already have an full-page EC flow (from the frontend form submition to backend API calls & redirects).  The frontend script will capture the redirect url and put it in the pop-up window, everything in the backend API calls remain the same.

Comment: @PP_pduan - interesting, does that mean the token generated in REST and Classic APIs are "the same"/interchangeable?

Comment: Yup it's not there in the public documents but working as an alternative of tampering the redirect url and inject it into the js, you may choose either way to implement

Comment: @EdSF for PayPal account payments, yes

Comment: @PP_pduan Awesome! Thank you - will now tinker :)

Comment: Hmm, I must be missing something. I do have a full-page EC flow using the REST API, with a backend redirect to the approval link the REST API gives you. In-Context puts it in a popup window, that's not a problem, but the approval link I'm redirecting to is still `https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-TOKEN`, which is not the right url for In-Context. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: @Y0lk exactly, the approval / redirect link is still in format of https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-TOKEN, but the in-context pop-up window will just work with that. Simple trick.

Comment: @PP_pduan I mean the page shows up in the pop-up window but it's not the right layout. It's the old, wide classic layout.

Comment: @Y0lk chances are you will fall-back to the classic layout due to seller or buyer country / region traffic ramp-up, this is controlled by PayPal, some time in the next year the ramp-up will be complete to support all regions. Please see here for the other eligibility limitations with in-context: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/

Comment: @PP_pduan From what I see, the merchant account I'm using should be eligible. Also, when I use this url `https://sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow` (like in my answer where I just str_replace for this url), it shows me the correct new In-Context layout. From what I understand, if I don't tamper the redirect url, it shows the classic layout because it's the old url and not the one we're supposed to use with In-Context.

Comment: @Y0lk This work pretty fine with US-US account payments (fully eligible for both seller and buyer country), and like I said paypal controls the ramp-up, so yes literally the safest way is to tamper the url to comply with the doc, as of the time.